# How to run apex Aura Methods in sequence order?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, javascript-controller

I want to fetch current user profile in doInit method and based on that profile would like to call another apex controller aura method and set parameters. I am following below procedure, but I see for community users the **profile name is coming as Undefined**

**Apex controller:** (testController)

```
 @AuraEnabled
    public static String fetchUser() {

    // query current user information  
      User current_user = [select id,Name,TimeZoneSidKey,Username,Alias,Country,Email,FirstName,LastName,IsActive,IsPortalEnabled,Profile.Name 
                 FROM User Where id =: userInfo.getUserId()];
       return current_user.Profile.Name;

    }     
     @AuraEnabled
    public static string updateRecord(String Values){
        // I have some logic to update based on Values string
    }
```

**Component:**

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" controller="testController" access="global" >

    <aura:attribute name="profile_name" type="String"/>
    <aura:attribute name="Values" type = "String"/> <!-- I get some values from other component in this attribute-->
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>

    <span> <lightning:button label="Next" variant="Brand" onclick="{!c.goToComponent}" value="Next" /></span>

</aura:component>
```

**contoller.js:**

```
 doInit:function(component){
    helper.method1(component);
}
```

**helper.js:**

```
 getCurrentUserProfile:function(cmp){
        var action = cmp.get("c.fetchUser");
        action.setCallback(this, function (response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            console.log('state'+state);
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                //var profile_name = ;
                cmp.set("v.profile_name", response.getReturnValue());
                console.log('=====profile'+ cmp.get("v.profile_name"));
                }
        });
        var self = this;
        action.setCallback(this,function(resp){

            self.method2(cmp);
        });

       $A.enqueueAction(action);
    },
    method2:function(cmp){
        var action = cmp.get('c.updateRecord');
        var profile = cmp.get("v.profile_name"); // it is coming as undefined in the console log
        console.log('helper profile' + profile);
        if (profile === 'xyz') {
            action.setParams({
                Values: cmp.get("v.Values")+'xyz'
            });
        }
        else if (profile === 'ABC') {
            console.log('internal one');
            action.setParams({
                Values: cmp.get("v.Values")+'ABC'
            });

        }
        action.setCallback(this, function (response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {


            } else if (state === "ERROR") {

            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
```

Comment: Why do you need two setCallbacks in getCurrentUserProfile()
Call method2() from success block.

Comment: Based on logged in user profile, I want to send some values to server side controller in doinit method, and this is required we cannot avoid it.

Comment: Try keeping method call   `self.method2(cmp);`    within  `if (state === "SUCCESS") {  ...  } `


in that way you can remove second `action.setCallback`  within the method `getCurrentUserProfile()`